# Call an oracle function from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

i have a function in oracle with this signature

```
test_fun(p_nat_no in number,p_number_type in number)  RETURN test_table
```

in the c# this is the code

```
string select = "test_fun"; 
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(helper.Global.ConnectionString))
{


    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(select, connection);
   // command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    OracleParameter PrmnatNo = new OracleParameter("p_nat_no ", natNo);//natNo
    command.Parameters.Add(PrmnatNo);

    OracleParameter pramNumberType = new OracleParameter("p_number_type ", numberType);
    command.Parameters.Add(pramNumberType);

    connection.Open();

    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            List<test_table> Tickets = new List<test_table>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Tickets.Add(GetPropertyTaxHelper(reader));

            }
            return Tickets;

        }
        else return null;
    }

}
```

Note: the function is work correctly from oracle.

but when trying to call the function from c# an error appears (invalide sql statement) even the function is correct and returns output from oracle ? any help? suggestions?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199713/c-sharp-call-oracle-stored-function

Comment: *an error appears*... Hmm...

Comment: the question is updated !

Comment: the error is (invalid SQL statement), but the function is compiled and working correctly from the database

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're using a reserved keyword (`select`) as the name of the string, since the compiler think that this is a [query expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx), the code above won't work.

The fix is obviously easy, change the name of the string named "select".

Comment: @alicebon Did you also changed the 1st parameter of the OracleCommand constructor ?