# Oracle function is not a procedure or is undefined. Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I am trying to call an Oracle function from C# that returns multiple rows but it is not working. Here is the function I am using:

```
create or replace function return_columns(
   tableName IN varchar
)
return types.ref_c
as
  c_result types.ref_c;
begin
  open c_result for
    select column_name 
      from all_tab_columns
     where table_name = tableName;

  return c_result;
end return_columns;
```

Here is the type:

```
create or replace package types
as
  type ref_c is ref cursor;
end;
```

I am in C# code calling the function like this:

```
OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=MySource;PASSWORD=MyPassword;USER ID=MyID");
OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand("MyID.RETURN_COLUMNS", oraConn);
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleParameter oraParam = new OracleParameter("tableName", OracleType.VarChar);
oraParam.Value = "MY_TABLE";
oraCmd.Parameters.Add(oraParam);

oraConn .Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);

ad.Fill(dt);

oraConn.Close();
```

And it keeps returning this error:

`'RETURN_COLUMNS' is not a procedure or is undefined ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

What is wrong with my Oracle function?

Comment: `What is wrong with my Oracle function? ` It is not the PL/SQL code itself that causes the problem, it's the way you call that function. It would be nice if you provided c# code that defines `myCommand` and parameters(`OracleParameter` variables)?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I Added the rest of the code for you to see

Comment: does the logged in user have access rights to that function?  Is the username "MyID" or a different oracle user?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, since I have that user accessing other functions I have written

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for calling a function in a package from C# and ODP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788509/code-for-calling-a-function-in-a-package-from-c-sharp-and-odp-net)

Comment: @OldProgrammer It's not the same scenario, I am looking to basically return a result set. Multiple rows, not just one number. I know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to define one more parameter, a parameter responsible for return value. Here is an example:

```
OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter("retVal", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

**Note #1:** The `retVal` parameter should be added first in the parameter list, otherwise you might receive `ORA-00306: wrong number or type of arguments..` error.

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(retVal);    -- ReturnValue parameter is being added first 
 cmd.Parameters.Add(tabName);   -- then goes everything else
```

**Note #2:** It would be better to use [ODP for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) instead of obsolete and deprecated Microsoft Oracle client (`System.Data.OracleClient`)

**Note #3:** Use `varchar2` data type instead of `varchar` in your PL/SQL code. As of now they are synonyms but their behavior might change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but this should get you moving in the right direction...

```
OracleParameter prm = cmd.CreateParameter();
prm.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
prm.ParameterName = "retcurse";
prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
oraCmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

OracleRefCursor rc = (OracleRefCursor)prm.Value;

// Not sure about this next part off the top of my head... 

OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds, "retcurse", rc);
// May also be this
// ad.Fill(ds, "retcurse", (OracleRefCursor)(oraCmd.Parameters["retcurse"].Value));
```