# How to run Oracle function from C# (vs 2012)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am trying to run function that i have in Oracle,i never worked with Oracle only with sql2008 sow i am new at this.

Here the function in Oracle that i need to call and get back integer:

```
create or replace function vb_new_serial return integer is
  Result integer;
begin
  select  vbserial.nextval into result from dual;
  return(Result);
end vb_new_serial;
```

This function dont get nothink it just retuns me integer.

I tried this ,but i getting error `PLS-00221: 'VB_NEW_SERIAL' is not a procedure or is undefined` :

```
  using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection con = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(strConn2))
    {
        con.Open();
        System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand cmd = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand("vb_new_serial");
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter returnVal = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("value", null);
       // cmd.Parameters.Add(returnVal);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//here i have error
        while (odr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odr.GetOracleValue(0));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788509/code-for-calling-a-function-in-a-package-from-c-sharp-and-odp-net

Comment: Are you sure you're connected under the right identity? Maybe wrong schema or missing package? `MY_PKG.VB_NEW_SERIAL` ?

Comment: Yes i see that post,and tes  i am sure i cheked this, i try evry thing Functhions.VB_NEW_SERIAL...and more combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first defined parameter should be the return value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

Comment: i am using System.Data.OracleClient and when i add this i dont have,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue and if i change this to Oracle.DataAccess.Client i will get error -PLS-00201: 'VB_NEW_SERIAL' must be declared

Comment: are you sure you are not just missing the namespace of `ParameterDirection`? put these on the top of your source file: `using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: If i using Oracle.DataAccess.Client and not System.Data.OracleClient all compilates,but with System.Data.OracleClient  OracleDbType and   ParameterDirection.ReturnValue not compilate i need to change it to cmd.Parameters.Add("Result",System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Int16, 1);

Comment: Changed all to Oracle.DataAccess.Client and added your code,on local pc dont work but on Server Pc (where it needs to be) it is start to work, thanx.