# how to call an oracle function in package on c#

Tags: c#, oracle

Here is my pl sql code (a package including a function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PACKAGE_REQUETE
IS
FUNCTION REQUETEFONCTION (ParametreId       requete.id%TYPE ) RETURN number;
END PACKAGE_REQUETE;
/
CREATE PACKAGE BODY  PACKAGE_REQUETE
IS
FUNCTION REQUETEFONCTION (ParametreId          requete.id%TYPE )
RETURN number IS
VariableId requete.id%TYPE ;
BEGIN
SELECT   id INTO   VariableId FROM   requete WHERE   id = ParametreId;
RETURN VariableId;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
THEN
    RETURN (-1);
END REQUETEFONCTION;
END PACKAGE_REQUETE;
/
```

I tried calling it from windows form application using `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteNonQuery` without luck.

Please find `C#` code below:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Authentification.chaineConnection);    
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PACKAGE_REQUETE.REQUETEFONCTION(1)", conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
```

Could you please help me find what is causing the error.

Comment: *but it dosen't work* is not an acceptable error. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'REQUETEFONCTION' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out as possibilities:

1) Check and ensure that the package is in a compiled state, and that you are connecting as the same user. If not the same user, you need to grant execute to that user and either create a synonym for the package or include the username in the function call.

2) Your initial code seems to be calling it like a procedure rather than a function as I don't see where the return parameter is getting stored, but I'm not a C# guy so that may be off-base.

There is a working example here: [executing function with C# and ODP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788509/code-for-calling-a-function-in-a-package-from-c-sharp-and-odp-net)