# Calling a PL_SQL function from inside c#

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, oracle11g

I have created a PL/SQL function and stored it in my oracle database.Now I want to call that function on clicking a button.
I am using visual studio and c#.

My humble attempt-

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comm = new OracleCommand();
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Connection = conn;
    String x1 = textBox1.Text;
    String x2 = textBox2.Text;

    comm.CommandText = "log_in";
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("c", OracleDbType.Varchar2, textBox1.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tt", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 256, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
    String z = comm.Parameters["z"].Value.ToString();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (z.Equals('1'))
    { MessageBox.Show("correct"); }
    conn.Close();
}
```

PL/SQL-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_in
(
    x IN VARCHAR2,
    y IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    match_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO match_count
    FROM student_login
    WHERE email = x
    AND password = y;
    IF match_count = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

note-my data source is .NET framework data provider for oracle and the answer is for odp.net

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: When I click the button the form closes

Comment: I'm just looking for a general answer also...it can be not specific to this question... whichever is easier

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point and figure out the value of `String Z`? Does it even reach that point? There's a lot of reasons why the form would close, so knowing more about the values of things will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code for calling a function in a package from C# and ODP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788509/code-for-calling-a-function-in-a-package-from-c-sharp-and-odp-net)

Comment: I am not using odp.net

Comment: there are two parameters for the function. you are only passing one input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has two input parameters, thus your call must also define two input parameter plus the return parameter. Method `Add(OracleParameter)` is possible but redundant.

It should be like this:

```
comm = new OracleCommand();
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Connection = conn;

comm.CommandText = "log_in";
comm.Parameters.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = textBox1.Text; 
   // As far as I remember "ParameterDirection.Input" is the default, so you may skip it
comm.Parameters.Add("y", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = textBox2.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("ret", OracleDbType.Byte, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
comm.Parameters["ret"].DbType = DbType.Byte;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

String returnValue = comm.Parameters["ret"].Value.ToString();
```

Actually I never used `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. If the code above does not work try this one instead:

```
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.CommandText = "BEGIN :ret := log_in(:x, :y); END;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had some problems with StoredProcedure. And finally get it working.

```
comm = new OracleCommand();
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Connection = conn;

comm.CommandText = "log_in";
// Important is to add returnValue as described bellow
OracleParameter retval = new OracleParameter("ret", OracleDbType.Varchar2 , 20);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
comm.Parameters.Add(retval);
comm.Parameters.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = textBox1.Text; 
comm.Parameters.Add("y", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = textBox2.Text;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

String returnValue = comm.Parameters["ret"].Value.ToString();
```